# Changing a list of tuples to a dictionary with unique item dates

Tags: python, list, dataframe, tuples

I am new to python, so I want to convert the result of a query to a list of dictionaries for example:

```
list_tuple= [('base', 5313, 3), ('case', 156, 3), ('standard', 482, 3),('base', 432, 4), ('case', 43, 4), ('standard', 44, 4)]
```

into a list of dictionary that looks like this:

```
[{x: 3, case: 100, base: 50, standard: 50}, {x: 4, case: 120, base: 55, standard: 75}]
```

I tried a loop with a defaultdict function:

```
    dict_tuple = defaultdict(dict)
    for x, y, z in list_tuple:
        dict_tuple[z][x] = y
```

the result was:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {3: {'base': 5313, 'case': 156, 'standard': 482}, 4: {'base': 432, 'case-certificate': 43, 'standard': 44}})
```

this was almost the case but still did not get the desired result, I do not know what am missing or is there a better way

Answer (score 0):

You were not far off with your idea and using the default dict to access the correct dict is a very good idea that I reused.

You're only missing adding the `"x"` in the dictionaries and putting them back in a list, which can be done with `key not in dict` and `dict.values()` method which are inherited from [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict).

```py
from collections import defaultdict

list_tuple = [
    ("base", 5313, 3),
    ("case", 156, 3),
    ("standard", 482, 3),
    ("base", 432, 4),
    ("case", 43, 4),
    ("standard", 44, 4),
]

temp_dict = defaultdict(dict)
for k, v, x in list_tuple:
    if "x" not in temp_dict[x]:
        temp_dict[x]["x"] = x
    temp_dict[x][k] = v

list_dict = list(temp_dict.values())

print(list_dict)
# [{'x': 3, 'base': 5313, 'case': 156, 'standard': 482},
#  {'x': 4, 'base': 432, 'case': 43, 'standard': 44}]
```